# Is updating a formerly updated BIOS again necessary after recovery or formatting?

Tags: laptop, bios

I updated my BIOS. But I wonder if I need to update BIOS again after recovery or formatting my laptop.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once updated, the BIOS sticks through formatting or updating. I have done this myself on numerous occasions for various computers and no need to re-update BIOS